# Error Acces phpmyadmin

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin - Error
Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!

how to solve this problem on ubuntu version 16.04 lts

Comment: it says wrong permissions. so what are the permission you have given ?

Comment: Please post more information on the issue this is scanty.